# How to fix System UI error crash in landscape mode

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, crashes

I get a pop up "Unfortunately, System ui has stopped" with Report and OK option. It happens whenever I changes my screen orientation to landscape mode.

Everything works fine except I am unable to change screen orientation.

I have Micromax Canvas A1 AQ4502 running stock android 6.0.1.

I have tried updating the android, clearing the cache, and resetting the phone to factory settings but I am still getting the same error.

Comment: I recommend you root your device and install a custom rom.

Comment: True, that's my last resort.